# error trying to run any simple r3-gui Rebol script but only when pre-downloaded

Tags: rebol, rebol3

So I downloaded Saphir's Rebol 3 for 32-bit Linux (I have Mint 17).  (As draegtun pointed out, no I didn't.  They don't seem to offer a Linux version at the moment.)

If `test.r` contains:

```
load-gui
view [text "Hello World!"]
```

...I get a window as expected and this:

```
$ ./r3-32-view-linux test.r 
Fetching GUI...
```

But if, instead, `test.r` contains:

```
do %r3-gui.r3
view [text "Hello World!"]
```

...I get this:

```
$ ./r3-32-view-linux test.r 
** Script error: / does not allow none! for its value2 argument
** Where: do resize-panel actor all foreach do-actor either -apply- apply case view do either either either -apply-
** Near: do bind bind/copy [
    size: viewport-box/bottom-right
    ...
```

The `r3-gui.r3` file, which I downloaded from http://development.saphirion.com/resources/r3-gui.r3 per [these instructions](http://learnrebol.com/rebol3_book.html#section-3.1), is in the same directory as `test.r`, which is the `cd` I run from.  IIUC, there shouldn't be any difference between the two results...obviously, I don't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might end up being more of a query than an answer but here goes!

Try the following from Rebol console:

```
$ ./r3-32-view-linux

>> source load-gui

load-gui: make function! [[
    {Download current Spahirion's R3-GUI module from web.}
    /local data
][
    print "Fetching GUI..."
    either error? data: try [load http://www.atronixengineering.com/r3/r3-gui.r3] [
        either data/id = 'protocol [print "Cannot load GUI from web."] [do err]
    ] [
        do data
    ]
    exit
]]
```

Now above is what I see using the Rebol View from Atronix.  If you are using the Saphirion Rebol View then you will see a different `r3-gui.r3` being loaded (should be the one you downloaded in your question).

The Atronix `r3-gui.r3` (dated 19-Feb-2014/14:39:59-5:00) is older than Saphirion version (dated: 19-May-2014/18:13:14+2:00).  However the Atronix Rebol View with their `r3-gui.r3` all works fine for me.

Next step in console:

```
>> write %r3-gui.r3 read http://www.atronixengineering.com/r3/r3-gui.r3
```

Now you can try your script again using this `%r3-gui.r3`.  However if you're definitely using the Saphirion binaries then it may not work and I would recommend downloading the Atronix Rebol binaries from http://atronixengineering.com/downloads.html and giving that a go.

Hope that helps?

Comment: I must have had the wrong binaries.  My output is like yours above.  However, the console step doesn't help: `** Script error: write does not allow url! for its data argument` but I get the gist.  I replaced the file and it works!  Many thanks!

Comment: @Kev - I had a funny feeling when I saw that you were using `r3-32-view-linux` that it was the Atronix binary.  And thats my oops on the final console step... i forgot a `read` there :(  Have now fixed answer.  Glad to hear it all works.